# How do I delete specific data from a YAML file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, yaml, command-line-interface

FYI I am new to programming :) I am using plain Ruby (not Rails)

I have made a command line app based on some features from The Sims. Users can create Sims (name, gender, life stage, trait) and that info is saved in database.yml.

I am trying to create a method which will allow the user to delete specific Sims from the database. Here's what my YAML file looks like:

```
---
:id:
  :name: Emily
  :gender: female
  :life_stage: adult
  :trait: friendly
---
:id:
  :name: Ben
  :gender: male
  :life_stage: elder
  :trait: mean
---
:id:
  :name: Josh
  :gender: child
  :life_stage: adult
  :trait: friendly
```

Here is my Ruby code. (The argument parsed into the method is the name of the Sim to be deleted):

```rb
def delete_sim(sim)
    log = File.open("../data/database.yml")
    YAML::load_stream(log) do |doc| 
        if sim == doc[:id][:name]
            delete.(doc)
            puts "You've successfully deleted #{sim}"
        else
            puts "Error"
            break
        end
    end
end
```

When I run the code, it displays the else error, which seems to indicate that line 4 isn't right. But what I'm mainly hoping to find out is the correct command to delete data from YAML (line 5). I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the YAML documentation.

If the solution is obvious to someone here, I'd much appreciate your insight :)

Thanks!

Comment: The trick here is to delete it from the file you must *rewrite* the file, that is you should have another file open for writing and conditionally write to it. Alternatively you could read this file in completely, strip out what you don't want, then write it back.

Comment: It's worth noting that `delete.(doc)` isn't valid Ruby code and doesn't mean anything. You can't delete a variable. The `delete` method is for things like `doc[:id].delete(:name)` which removes the `:name` property.

Comment: That's the most straight-forward way to tackle this problem. There's no way to just remove sections of a file. That's what a database is for, like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) for example.

Comment: @tadman When you say `There's no way to just remove sections of a file` I'd say that's true from a pragmatic point of view when dealing with text files (and YAML in particular), but Ruby *does* support low-level read/writes with offsets and seeks using the [IO module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/IO.html). That won't help this OP, but may add some nuance for future visitors who are using on-disk objects that can benefit from it.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs That allows you to skip around and re-write things, which can work for fixed-length data structures, but isn't the case here. There's no operating system call for "delete chunk" like there is for strings.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You have three YAML documents in your file, not a single document. When you load your file as a YAML stream, you actually get a single Array containing three Hash objects. For example:

```rb
require 'yaml'

yaml = YAML.load_stream File.read('database.yml')
#=> [{:id=>{:name=>"Emily", :gender=>"female", :life_stage=>"adult", :trait=>"friendly"}}, {:id=>{:name=>"Ben", :gender=>"male", :life_stage=>"elder", :trait=>"mean"}}, {:id=>{:name=>"Josh", :gender=>"child", :life_stage=>"adult", :trait=>"friendly"}}]

yaml.class
#=> Array

yaml.count
#=> 3

yaml.first.class
#=> Hash
```

You have other problems with your code as well, but understanding the object class that you're working with is really the most important step.

### Solution

To remove an item from this type of collection, you'll have to iterate through each element and then write the modified results back out as separate YAML documents. For example:

```rb
require 'yaml'

DB = 'database.yml'

def write_database sims
  File.open(DB, 'w') { |f| f.puts sims.map(&:to_yaml) }
  sims
end

def delete_sim name
  sims = YAML.load_stream File.read(DB)
  raise ArgumentError, "no sim found: #{name}" if
    sims.filter { |sim| sim.dig(:id, :name) == name }.none?
  sims.reject! { |sim| sim[:id][:name] == name }
  write_database sims
end

delete_sim 'Ben'
#=> [{:id=>{:name=>"Emily", :gender=>"female", :life_stage=>"adult", :trait=>"friendly"}}, {:id=>{:name=>"Josh", :gender=>"child", :life_stage=>"adult", :trait=>"friendly"}}]

delete_sim 'Dave'
#=> ArgumentError (no sim found: Dave)
```

If you're using this as a database, you should also consider refactoring to a [YAML::Store](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) instead of a concatenated stream of YAML documents to take advantage of easier reading and writing, to provide support for transactions, and to handle file locking and prevent race conditions. However, the code above will solve the problem you're currently experiencing.

Comment: "When you load your file as a YAML stream, you actually get a single Array containing three Hash objects" – The OP is using the block form of `YAML::load_stream`, which yields each document in sequence to the block. The only problem with the OP's code is that they simply break out of the loop as soon as the first sim does not match the one to be deleted.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Whether or not one uses the block form, the database file will still need to be rewritten, or the modified data passed to some other in-memory variable or method. The current code does neither, which is what my answer is focused on, and why I recommend refactoring it.

Comment: BTW, to avoid the appearance of bike-shedding, I agree with the first part of your statement: `The OP is using the block form of YAML::load_stream, which yields each document in sequence to the block.` That's something I'd overlooked, but doesn't really change the fact that the entire YAML file needs to be rewritten to persist the changes.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the code, it displays the else error, which seems to indicate that line 4 isn't right.

Line 4 is correct. However, consider what happens if `sim` is not `'Emily'`?

*As soon as* the `sim` that was passed as an argument does not match the name you are looking for, you go into the `else` branch and then `break` out of the loop. That means you *never* look at the second, third, etc. document in your YAML stream.

Either the first `sim` is the one you are looking for, then you delete it, or the first `sim` is not the one you are looking for, then you print an error and terminate the loop.

The simplest possible modification I can think of that should fix your code, would be something like this:

```ruby
def delete_sim(sim)
  log = File.open('../data/database.yml')

  YAML::load_stream(log) do |doc| 
    next unless sim == doc[:id][:name]

    delete.(doc)
    puts "You've successfully deleted #{sim}"

    return
  end

  puts "Error"
end
```

Comment: Your answer may fix the branching issue, but will still raise NameError for `delete.(doc)`, and won't really solve the OP's problem with removing a specific record from the on-disk DB.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me that the code in the question is not the *entire* code, since `delete_sim` doesn't even get called anywhere. So, `delete` must naturally be defined in the part of the code that is not shown.

Comment: It's not just that it's undefined in the OP's posted code. It's a syntax issue as well, as `.()` isn't generally valid, and any edge cases (something like `foo[idx]` for `Array#[](idx)` comes to mind) would have to be handled as a special case by the parser/interpreter.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: `delete.(doc)` is perfectly valid, it is simply syntactic sugar for `delete.call(doc)`, so as long as `delete` returns something which responds to `call`, there will be no problem. Since `delete` is not shown in the OP's code, we don't know what it does, but we can assume that it is the method which is actually responsible for deleting the document from the document stream.